# How to perform filtering with a Django JSONField?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-1.9, django-jsonfield

I'm using PostgreSQL and this new field from Django 1.9, JSONField. So I got the following data:

```
id|data
1 |[{'animal': 'cat', 'name': 'tom'}, {'animal': 'dog', 'name': 'jerry'}, {'animal': 'dog', 'name': 'garfield'}]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to filter in this list of json.

I tried something like `object.filter(data__contains={'animal': 'cat'}` but I know this is not the way.

Also I've been thinking in get this value and filter it in my code:

```
[x for x in data if x['animal'] == 'cat']
```

Comment: Did you read the comprehensive documentation on [querying JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield)? What is unclear?

Comment: The above link doesn't work anymore. [Querying JSONfield now lives here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield).

Comment: @brunoparga
 Maybe you can find something useful here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield

Answer (score 129, accepted):

As per the Django [JSONField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield), it explains that that the `data` structure matches python native format, with a slightly different approach when querying.

If you know the structure of the JSON, you can also filter on keys as if they were related fields:

```
object.filter(data__animal='cat')
object.filter(data__name='tom')
```

By array access:

```
object.filter(data__0__animal='cat')
```

Your [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#containment-and-key-lookups) example is almost correct, but your data is in a list and requires:

```
object.filter(data__contains=[{'animal': 'cat'}])
```

Comment: that's it, thanks!! just one more thing, am I able to filter dates? Instead of 'animal' I got a key called 'start_date' which contains a date in ISO 8601 format

Comment: I don't think you can as they're only stored as strings. I think you'd have to pull out all the dates and then compare them in python. If it was possible you can test it by doing this comparison: `data__datetime__lte=other_datetime` or any of the other query shortcuts.

Comment: yes, it works... but only accessing an element array `data__0__datetime__lte='2015-03-12'`. do you have in mind any other way to search in the whole list? thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to apply a date filter to a JSON field? I tried `data__time__date_lte=date.today()`. But I am getting an error  `Failed to handle exception Object of type Timestamp is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: nice very deep understanding of the feature!