# Problem with filter in django orm by json field

Tags: sql, json, django, orm

Could someone help me with django orm filter
I am trying to filter data by some key in json filed (Postgres, jsonb field)
Field in postgres table contains something like

```
{ "pet": "dog", "name": "my_lovely_dog" }
```

I build filter like:

```
cond = {"field_name__pet": some_variable}
qs = qs.filter(**cond)
```

But when I watch result sql query I see something like:

```
Select * from "table_name" where ("table"."my_field" -> pet) = '"dog"'
```

How I can do it correctly? Why django use "" inside ''? And why django not put key from json in ""?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django JSONField filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389871/django-jsonfield-filtering)

Comment: Thank you! This answer helped me )

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve this issue is:

I use field__contains = {"dog":"dogs_name"} and it work

@Jim
Thank you