# Find an object in Django using a list inside JSONField

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-models

I have such a model in `Django`:

```
class Event(models.Model):                                                                                                 
    EVENT_TYPE_CHOICES = [(e, e.value) for e in EVENT_TYPE]                                                                
    event_type = models.TextField(choices=EVENT_TYPE_CHOICES)                                                              
                                                                                                                           
    date_of_event = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)                                              
    event_data = JSONField()
```

And there is the `event_data` `JSONField` there which has the following structure:

```
    'project_id': project_id,                                                                                       
    'family_id': family_id,                                                                                         
    'variant_data': variant_data_list,                                                                              
    'username': user.username,                                                                                      
    'email': user.email,
```

Where `variant_data_list` is a list of such `dict` objects with `3` `str` values:

```
{'xpos': xpos, 'ref': ref, 'alt': alt}
```

Now, I need a way to find unique `Event` model object based on the supplied `variant_data_list` (each object inside of it should be found within a single `Event`s' `variant_data_list`, is it possible to achieve somehow? The number of items in `variant_data_list` is from `1` to `3`.

Otherwise I am thinking of generating unique ids based on the `variant_data_list` each time it is written to `postgres` (but not sure how to make it either). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to filter on json fields as illustrated in this answer ([Django JSONField filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389871/django-jsonfield-filtering)) - the following is untested:

```
# filter for events with a specific variant_data list:
Event.objects.filter(event_data__variant_data=[<the list>])

# filter for events with specific items in the variant data list:
Event.objects.filter(
    event_data__variant_data__contains='item1', 
    event_data__variant_data__contains='item2',
    ...
)
```

You can get a list of objects by looping over all your events which is likely less efficient:

```
events = [
    event for event in Event.objects.all() if event.event_data['variant_data'] == [<the list>]
]
```

You can also override your save method on events to as you suggested:

```
class Event(...):

    variant_data_id = models.CharField(...)
  
    ...
   
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.variant_data_id = some_hash_method(self.event_data['variant_list']

        super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement it with hash correctly, so that the collision would never happen. The first method may not work because the order of the objects in the list can be different, but the order should not matter.

Comment: Well the variant_data_id field itself doesn't need to be unique, but maybe you want it to... You can change your query to account for the ordering of the items in the list by using `contains` - see the edit.