# how can i filter field django jsonfield that is datetime?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-jsonfield

I want to filter base on time field in jsonfield,but this field store as string and i can not use this query:

```py
Notification.objects.filter(Q(data__payload__request_visit_time__gte=timezone.now()))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By comments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36390908/7787478) it seems to be possible if you pass datetime value in your query as string:

```py
Notification.objects.filter(Q(data__payload__request_visit_time__gte=timezone.now().isoformat()))
```